# Text to be written must be a length-one character vector when trying to pass dates in dateRange() input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the dataframe below with some datetime objects and I want to extract just the date parts in order to put them inside a `dateRange()` input. But when I run the app I get :

```
ERROR: Text to be written must be a length-one character vector
```

I tried to use `c()` before the df$EventaDate but without result.

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)

df = data.frame(timestring = c("2015-12-12 13:34:56", "2015-12-14 16:23:32"),
                localzone = c("America/Los_Angeles", "America/New_York"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$moment = as.POSIXct(df$timestring, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

df = df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(localtime = force_tzs(moment, localzone))

df$moment<-as.Date(df$moment, "%Y-%m-%d")



## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Date range input: yyyy-mm-dd',
                   start = df$moment , end = df$moment 
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing both values, where only one is required, see `min` and `max`:

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(timestring = c("2015-12-12 13:34:56", "2015-12-14 16:23:32"),
                localzone = c("America/Los_Angeles", "America/New_York"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$moment <- as.POSIXct(df$timestring, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(localtime = force_tzs(moment, localzone))

df$moment <- as.Date(df$moment)

## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Date range input: yyyy-mm-dd',
                   start = min(df$moment) , end = max(df$moment)
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: so obvious tnx.